# Shrink / collapse overflowing text

Tags: java, html, css, web, mern

Please check the attached image. As you can see, text is overflowing outside the div. I just want to collapse the overflowing text and display "Read more" in the end. While user click "read more" text should be expanded.

I'm working on a next js project.

[Screenshot of div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5Sxt.png)

My requirement is to collapse the text to specified lines not to break the text from specified lines.

Comment: If you type "div overflow text" in the search bar, you'll find a TON of answers regarding to this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow?retiredLocale=de

Comment: Why the java rag?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Card component like this:

```
export default function Card() {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div className={`${style.collapsible_text} ${expanded ? '' : style.collapsed}`}>
        {/* Card text goes here */}
      </div>
      <p onClick={() => setExpand(!expand)}>{expand? "read more..." : "read less..."</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then, apply the following css to the Card component:

```
.collapsible_text {
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.collapsed {
  max-height: 50px;
}
```